# Attraction and hormones levels

Tags: neuroscience, brain, endocrinology

Why do we ignore all imperfections in people we fall in love with for a couple of months, but after a certain period we start noticing imperfections?

Can hormones - or any chemical - be used to influence someone to fall in love with you?

Comment: Related question: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17250/biology-in-romantic-love  @murmansk

Comment: @Mesentery I would like to say that dopamine won't cause "romantic" attachment. It would only cause sexual attachment.

Comment: @kirill2485 I don't understand why u commented this :)

Comment: well thats what the question asks for. the other answer you linked said that dopamine is a love hormone, when it is a reward hormone, and I would like to make sure that flo knows that dopamine is not gonna cause "love" or "bonding"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The chemical/hormone that causes attraction is called serotonin. That's what causes attraction between two people. Theoretically, chemicals can be used to make people fall in love with you, such as MDMA, which increases serotonin levels. If the "animal" (such as a cat or a monkey), was in the same room as you and you gave the cat MDMA and you were the only one in the room, the cat would bind with you and seratonin would be released.

This is why MDMA and methamphetamine are known to cause homosexuality and fetishism, for the drug tricks the human into thinking that serotonin is formed with a guy who he is hanging out with or what he is doing at the very moment.

Another hormone that is a "love" hormone is called oxytocin, but this chemical will only cause bonding once the love is formed.

In short, serotonin makes someone fall in love with you, while oxytocin will keep someone in love with you.

Comment: References? This sounds like a tremendous oversimplification and exaggeration.

Comment: I didn't get this from any sources, just personal experience from participating in numerous clinical trials + knowing the science behind it. But if you want a source:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3183515/ . "This was because oxytocin is not unlike the drug ecstasy, which triggers the release of serotonin, dopamine and oxytocin in the brain and heightens users’ feelings of trust and intimacy, even among complete strangers. "

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant Alright, I found an article that shows that MDMA is used as a date-rape drug by making the victim fall in love with the offender: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16681170

Comment: No, the paper doesn't say that at all! It says that prosecutors, police  officers, and toxicologists have made that argument in date rape cases, but that it isn't really supported by the known psychology of the effects of MDMA. From the paper: "MDMA and amphetamines are not usually able to rob a conscious person of their free will. It is for this reason that producing unconsciousness is a likely aim of the per­son intending to perpetrate a drug-facilitated sexual assault, as distinct from those intending to engage in seduction, in which suggestion may play a significant role."

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant "sexual desire linked with methamphetamine use, remove a person's ability to give a reasoned consent, turning the person into "a helpless slave" to their own sexual desires and those of the alleged perpetrator. "

Comment: That's a selective quotation. The full quote is: "However, *some law enforcement agents and others have recently obtained convictions by arguing* that the empathy· generating and sensual effects of MDMA. and an occasional increase in disinhibition and sexual desire linked with methamphetamine use, remove a person's ability to give a reasoned consent. turning the person into "a helpless slave". That is, it is an assertion by law enforcement, not a demonstrated fact, and certainly not one demonstrated by that paper. (emphasis mine).

Comment: I've once overdosed on MDMA and all it was was serotonin syndrome and thats it..

Comment: If you actually read the paper rather than just the abstract you'd see that that's part of their point. Alcohol and GBH are used as date rape drugs because they render the victim comatose, and completely unable to resist. MDMA doesn't render the victim unconscious, so it's less likely to be useful as a date rape drug. It may disinhibit people, and that may lead some people into activities which they later regret, but that's a pretty far cry from turning them into sex slaves.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant There's also this: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4023138/

but it doesn't say much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59268/discussion-between-charles-e-grant-and-kirill2485).

Comment: For anyone reading comments, we ended the discussion with this link: https://www.hindawi.com/journals/pd/2012/603631/